# How to make LESS different with each environment in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, less

I'm using `Meteor` with less package, and trying to make a variable different on each environment. For example:

```
// on Dev
@staticPath: '/'

// on Production
@staticPath: 'http://s.mydomain.com/'
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult to do this comparing the effort you have to put in to compared with what you get.

You can create a package in your project that is a 'dev mode' package and another thats a production mode package

```
meteor create --package debugmode
meteor create --package productionmode
```

In the packages directory you should have two packages, in the `debugmode` package you can edit the `package.js` file and add `debugOnly: true` into the `Package.describe` method.

You can also add `api.use("debugmode", "less")` to the `Package.onUse(function(api) {` section of it. This ensures that if `productionmode` has a variable, then `debugmode` will override it.

You'll also need an `api.use("less")` in the `productionmode` package since its dependent on `less`.

In both packages you will have to use `api.add_files` to add any less files that are production mode or debug mode. Keep in mind debug mode overrides production mode so the variable names need to match. If you declare a production mode variable it will have to be nullified by the debug mode package.

Lastly add the packages in with `meteor add productionmode debugmode`

I've never personally tried this, but a variation of it in some way (perhaps including all the less files) in the two packages should work.

Comment: Thanks I ended up make myself a package that reads environment variable and passes to `less parser`. https://atmospherejs.com/jwall149/less-env-globalvars